# Use network path without mounting as a drive

Tags: macos, mount, smb

I've recently moved to OS X from Windows, and I wish to point a couple of programs towards a network share. On Windows I could open a program's *Settings* and enter a path as `//my.network.share/path` and I'm trying to find out if this is possible in OS X.

I know from [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36443/how-can-i-open-windows-network-links-on-mac-os-x) question that I can mount the network share and then point a program towards it, but Windows allows me to enter such a path without the share having been mounted. I had hoped that I could enter the network path prefixed with `smb://` but OS X won't allow this.

The reason I don't want to mount the share is that it won't always be present. Therefore, I only want to *require* the network location when I open a specific program.

Is this possible in OS X or do I need to mount the share first?

Comment: ***"..I wish to point a couple of programs towards a network share.."*** *&* ***"..On Windows I could open a program's settings and enter a path.."***                  What exactly do you mean by these?

Comment: For example, using Calibre for managing ebooks, and it requires a library which may be located on the local computer or a server. When setting up this library, Calibre presents a text field into which you can enter a network path.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a screenshot? If you post an image, I'll try to point you towards the closest OS X equivalent or a reasonable substitute.

Comment: A screenshot of... the text box into which one enters the path?

Comment: You have a problem which you are trying to solve. I don't fully understand the problem or the question, but I understand enough of it to know that I may be able to help you with it, provided some clarification. Take a photo or provide some kind of accurate visual representation of what you're attempting to describe so that I can actually "see" the problem for myself. Then I will try my best to help you.

Comment: Try to include the entire screenshot. Minimal cropping is best.